# How does this javascript self executing function / Structure work

Tags: javascript

I inherited an application, and i see this JavaScript structure everywhere.
What is the reason for creating it like that. I get that it is an anonymous function and that `PaymentOffersOverview` gets passed to it.

```
var PaymentOffersOverview = PaymentOffersOverview || {};

(function(PaymentOffersOverview) {
    var App = {};

    App.Settings = {
        Id: some Id value
        // Some Code
    };

    App.ShowLoader = function (message) {
            // Some Code
        };

    PaymentOffersOverview.App = App;
})(PaymentOffersOverview);
```

But what i don't get is the last line. `})(PaymentOffersOverview);` Why does it get passed in again?

```
// Then the code can be used as follow

alert(PaymentOffersOverview.App.Settings.Id);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u15ekmfw/)

Comment: the last line is the value of the first parameter your anonymous function accepts.

Comment: I think you need to read up on IIFE http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: @DavidJones - Thanks I will, i think the problem was that i was not sure what to look for

Comment: @R4nc1d now worries. You might have seen this type of thing when passing in jQuery to a IIFE. I think k0pernikus' answer sums it up well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not get passed in again. By the last line, the closure gets the `PaymentOffersOverview` as it is self-invoking. If it wasn't passed, the `PaymentOffersOverview` within the closure would be `undefined`.

```
// definition of local variable
var PaymentOffersOverview = PaymentOffersOverview || {};

(function(param) {
    // now we are in the context of the closure where param refers to
    // PaymentOffersOverview, yet PaymentOffersOverview is not defined
    // within this scope. It is param. 
    // You can use any name here, using the same is just for convinience.
    var App = {};

    App.Settings = {
        Id: some Id value
        // Some Code
    };

    App.ShowLoader = function (message) {
            // Some Code
        };

    param.App = App;
})(PaymentOffersOverview); // passing of the variable
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually makes completely sense now. The weird thing for me was that  PaymentOffersOverview got passed into the function with the same name as the object declared at the top. So the param variable makes more sense.